# How to change my hostname in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I just installed Ubuntu in my laptop, and I want to switch my root hostname to xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com

So, when I type "hostname" command, it will show up like:
xxxxxxx

Should I be manually changing the hostname via using text editors or is there a specific way to connect my root to xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using the command :

```
sudo hostname your-new-name
```

this will change the hostname until you restart. if you want to change the hostname permanently you should edit  the file `/etc/hostname` and restart your computer. You should also edit `/etc/hosts` and change the line coantains the address 127.0.1.1 otherwise many commands will cease functioning:

```
127.0.1.1     your-new-hostname
```

Comment: In any case, it should be 127.0.0.1 :D

Comment: yes but the hsotname must be changed

Answer (score 0):

type hostname followed by the desired hostname:

```
hostname sitename.com
```

and edit /etc/hostname

```
echo sitename.com > /etc/hostname
```

or use any editor like vim or nano

Answer (score 0):

You can set hostname as follows

> $hostnamectl set-hostname xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com

when you set hostname as "xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com", you get

> Static hostname xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com
>
> Pretty hostname xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com

Check using

> hostnamectl

command

The pretty hostname is a free-form UTF8 host name for presentation to the user.

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/System_Administrators_Guide/s1_Using_Hostnamectl.html

A host name can be a free-form string up to 64 characters in length, however it is recommended that the static and transient names consists only of 7 bit ASCII lower-case characters, no spaces or dots, and limits itself to the format allowed for DNS domain name labels, even though this is not a strict requirement.

The hostnamectl tool will enforce the following: Static and transient host names to consist of a-z, A-Z, 0-9, “-”, “_” and “.” only, to not begin or end in a dot, and to not have two dots immediately following each other. The size limit of 64 characters is enforced.